# Upgrading pip uninstalled my pip and now I can't reinstall it on Mac OS X

Tags: python, pip

Edit: Forgot to add, it's on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite

This is one of the reasons I never update my pip because I was afraid this would happen and I would shatter some backwards compatibility ... alas.

I upgraded my pip and suddenly everything broke down and now I can't get it to work.

```
Last login: Thu May 24 10:52:09 on ttys000
Hi Jan
~> pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (211kB)
    100% |################################| 215kB 2.7MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil
  Found existing installation: python-dateutil 2.4.2
    Uninstalling python-dateutil-2.4.2:
      Successfully uninstalled python-dateutil-2.4.2
Successfully installed python-dateutil-2.7.3
You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So basically I tried to install pandas again because my dateutil suddenly broke down ... something to do with building a fontcache? I don't know I thought a reinstall would fix the problem. Then it suggested that I should upgrade my pip. Reluctantly I did try to upgrade my pip,

```
~> pip install --upgrade pip
zsh: correct 'pip' to '.pip' [nyae]? n

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting pip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 811kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.0
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 752, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
exit 2
```

Well. Shit. It stopped halfway and now I am left without pip at all!

```
~>
exit 2
~> pip install dateutil
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~> pip
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~> pip install
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~>
exit 127
~>
exit 127
~> pip
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~>
exit 127
~> pip install
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~> pip install
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~>
exit 127
~>
exit 127
```

Here I try to use curl to install pip: doesn't work,

```
~> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1603k  100 1603k    0     0   724k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  724k
~> python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
/var/folders/47/2fdkbcyx0pzf0l9pprsl8ksw0000gn/T/tmpCLBru6/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/var/folders/47/2fdkbcyx0pzf0l9pprsl8ksw0000gn/T/tmpCLBru6/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/var/folders/47/2fdkbcyx0pzf0l9pprsl8ksw0000gn/T/tmpCLBru6/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 4.2MB/s
praw 3.5.0 has requirement six==1.10, but you'll have six 1.11.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.0
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.0:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I try to use easy_install to install pip, doesnt work either,

```
exit 1
~> pip
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~> pip install
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~> pip install 9.0.0
zsh: correct 'pip' to 'pp' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pip
exit 127
~> easy_install -U pip
zsh: correct 'pip' to '.pip' [nyae]? n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2928, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2914, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2941, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==5.4.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
exit 1
```

Some more desperate attempts,

```
~> which pip
zsh: correct 'pip' to '.pip' [nyae]? n
pip not found
exit 1
~> sudo easy_install pip
zsh: correct 'pip' to '.pip' [nyae]? n
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2928, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2914, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2941, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==5.4.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
exit 1
~>
```

I'm usually the kind of guy to just read the instructions and follow the commands listed but I broke my pip by upgrading and I'm having trouble reinstalling.

**EDIT: SOLVED IT**

```
~> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12537  100 12537    0     0  71398      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 71640
ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools
Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-33.1.1.zip
Extracting in /var/folders/47/2fdkbcyx0pzf0l9pprsl8ksw0000gn/T/tmpdT5I0V
Now working in

 ...

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-33.1.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==33.1.1
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==33.1.1

~> sudo easy_install pip==9.0.0
Searching for pip==9.0.0
Best match: pip 9.0.0
Adding pip 9.0.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.5 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip==9.0.0
Finished processing dependencies for pip==9.0.0
```

Comment: You are getting permission denied errors, can you try `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` ?

Comment: @ShivamSingh It completely removed my installation of pip. When I try what you suggest I get "sudo: pip: command not found"

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Answer (score 1):

It's a permission error.

After you download `pip` like so:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

Try doing this:

`sudo python get-pip.py`

instead of just `python get-pip.py`

Comment: Forgot to add, it's on Mac OSX, sorry. Have changed the original post.

Comment: not sure, but doesn't `sudo` work on Mac OSX as well?

Comment: This saved my life :D

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

since the messages shows `Permission Denied` and your pip seems to have been uninstalled.

Comment: Forgot to add, it's on Mac OSX, sorry. Have changed the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-install pip from the Linux command line:

**Uninstall**
Uninstall PIP On Debian/Ubuntu (check python version)

```
# sudo apt remove python-pip    #python 2
# sudo apt remove python3-pip   #python 3
```

Uninstall PIP On CentOS and RHEL

```
# sudo yum remove epel-release 
# sudo yum instremove python-pip
```

**Then install again:**

Install PIP On Debian/Ubuntu (check python version)

```
# sudo apt install python-pip   #python 2
# sudo apt install python3-pip  #python 3
```

Install PIP On CentOS and RHEL

```
# sudo yum install epel-release 
# sudo yum install python-pip
```

Comment: Forgot to add, it's on Mac OSX, sorry. Have changed the original post.